# Maximize system of non-linear equations

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

How to maximize $$Y = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{a_ix_i}{b_ix_i+c_i}$$
Given the following constraints:

- $\sum_{i=0}^n x_i = X$ (X is a constant)
- $x_0, x_1, ..., x_n >= 0$

In the above, $a, b, c$ are vectors with known input (all integers). $X$ is also known. Thus, I need to find how to split $X$ to optimize $Y$.

I have tried using the [Linear-Fractional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-fractional_programming) to transform it into a system of linear equations, over which to use the Simplex Method, but I have a hard time translating the constraints. And I am not even sure that is the correct approach to this problem.

Comment: As far as I can see, it is not possible to bring back this problem to an LP.

Comment: I would just use an NLP solver for this. A good one is IPOPT (open source).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the constraint across $i$, the Charnes-Cooper transformation from linear fractional programming to linear programming does not apply here, but you can instead transform to second-order cone programming, as shown in my answer here: https://or.stackexchange.com/a/8959/500

Comment: RobPratt, thank you for taking the time to share your other answer. 
Just in case someone stumbles across this, the difference between my problem and the one linked is that I have `a*x` in the numerator, while the linked problem has `x`, but that is easily "fixed" by dividing both sides with `a_i`, thus obtaining `x / (b/a*x + c/a)`, and then you can follow the guidance from the linked answer.